# Not being paid for meetings or training

Tags: salary, united-states, law

I've been with a company for two years. My initial training was done on the clock, but since then, all other training (we get new online training about once every few months) is done outside of work. It's required, and long ago I was told I would be paid for it, but I have not noticed it on any paychecks.

Similarly, the few first meetings were paid for, but since then I did not notice them on my paychecks either. I've asked and my boss said they were included.

When other co-workers said they were not paid either, I concluded that we just would not be paid for it. Then, I did some research, and I found that [employers are required to pay for training and meetings](http://www.dol.gov/whd/regs/compliance/whdfs53.htm).

I have not spoken to my boss about these potential missing payments for the past six months, and I've already put in my two weeks notice.

Would it be best to approach my boss about this matter (again), or contact HR? I have no proof I wasn't paid, but I have no proof I was, either.

Comment: If you're leaving anyway, ask about it.  Also why can't you prove it?  Wouldn't that imply that you would have a higher pay that pay period if it were included?  It would show up on your pay slips, surely...?

Comment: The pay slips show the total hours I worked. I don't know how they do it, but I assume one way is to add training/meetings to the total hours worked, and I wouldn't know how many hours I had before then.

Comment: Given that you have given notice and can't prove anything anyway, just let it go and get enjoy your new role.  It serves no purpose and will just leave a bad taste in everybody's mouth.  Move on :)

Comment: This is the first I'm hearing of getting paid (separately) for meetings. Unless meetings are out of office hours? Can you elaborate?

Comment: Voting to close, we don't give legal advice, and anything else is company specific to your situation, and so off topic for this site.

Comment: How many hours do you work per week and how many hours do you spend in meetings per week? Do the numbers on your time slips adhere to your own records/memory? You don't need to document every individual hour for the past two years. Just calculate your normal schedule, say, 08:00-17:00 as 8 hours worked (and 1 hour break, for example).

Answer (score 3):

You don't provide any context for your employment compensation. But unless you are an hourly employee in the U.S. you are considered to be a salaried employee.

Which means if you are salaried and attend meetings outside of normal business hours, there is no expectation of additional compensation. A salaried employee might have normal work hours but you are generally expected to be available 24/7 unless you make other arrangements.

If you are an hourly staffer and the agreement was you should be paid for hours beyond your normal workday, then you should bring it up with your supervisor or human resources.

Comment: 60% of workers in the US are paid hourly. Furthermore, the very nature of the OP's question indicates they are paid hourly.

Comment: I'd say one is not generally available 24/7 as a salaried employee, unless otherwise requested. And if so, for a limited time and for a specific reason (on call for a weekend to fix production malfunctions). Being on service 24/7 ready to come in at any whim of ones employer sounds more like slavery and not like a modern employee.

Comment: @jakegould I do not object to being available outside regular hours when the need arises, but to the default of needing to be on call 24/7. And the job of CEO is quite different in scope and payment than the majority of salaried employees.

Answer (score 0):

This does nothing for your present situation but can help your future self avoid the same question (BTW Jane S made a great point about moving on).

Track your hours worked in a spreadsheet (Excel, Libre Office, whatever). Every day as you punch in/out, make a note of the time and enter it in your spreadsheet. It can simply be a list of numbers, but you can use formulas to calculate exactly how many hours you've worked.

I made one that's complete overkill--I can clock out for lunch or a doctor visit--but the basic sheet is pretty easy to do.  If your paycheck hours align within a couple minutes to your spreadsheet, you and your employer agree on how much time you're spending at work.

I use my sheet even after becoming salaried again; it helps me stay grounded.  We all have those weeks we simply don't feel like being at work, but I can look and see I only did 38 hours this week and remind myself to quit complaining.  Or when I put in 72 hours, it gives me hard proof for bragging rights.
:-)